# TweenMax Rotate, Opacity, and Scale

Tags: rotation, scale, opacity, gsap

I'm trying to make the images on this page rotate, scale and change opacity all at the same time, like some images on this site do;

http://soyouwanttogotorisd.com/

And this is my site;

http://www.ducklingfarm.com

I'm using TweenMax, and this is my code;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    TweenMax.from( $('#homeImg'), .5, 
    {css:{scale:.05, opacity:0, rotation: 180}, ease:Quad.easeInOut}), 400,-400);
 });
```

But nothing's happening...

Please help me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found an answer!

http://forums.greensock.com/topic/8480-scale-rotate-and-opacity/#entry33133

I used this code;

```
$(window).load (function(){
  TweenMax.from( $('.homeImg > img'), 0.5,
        {css:{scale:0.05, opacity:0, rotation: 180}, 
        ease:Quad.easeInOut
  });
});
```